# Network error: Connection refused putty

Tags: putty

I am trying to log in to my server with ssh keys (I use putty to do it) but every time I try to connect it says **Network error: Connection refused.**

What could be the possible error? And how to rectify it?

Answer (score 0):

'Connection refused' usually means that server computer does not have ssh server installed or launched.

Sometimes firewall blocks incoming connection. In such case you will have to enable incoming ssh connections in firewall's config.

Comment: I have 2 instances running on AWS, 1 instance is connected properly but the 2nd one is giving network error.

Comment: Check your PuTty configuration for 2nd instance if it has correct host/port.

Try to connect with ssh command from 1st instance to 2nd instance then in opposite direction.